# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' and System changes

Tags: python-2.7

I know there are tons of posts about the `AttributeError: NoneType...` but they don't seem to apply. My code has been working for years, and this week i am getting this error. Also, I am not an expert coder.

I checked the Python Path, and it seems normal:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

When i try to edit the code in Komodo IDE, the autocomplete works fine, e.g., `self.ser.write(string)` has the write in the suggestion menu.

It is as if it can't find the library. Is that right? How can that be?

I am using XP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks more as if your variable self.ser has NoneType, so you might need to take a look at the place where you initialize self.ser in your class.

**Edit**: Looking around it seems that the library you are using is pyserial2.7 right? I have seen at the documentation [here](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#classes) a class called just `Serial`, which also takes as input a port and a baudrate, so I guess it might be the class you need. Maybe you are getting `NoneType` because that `SerialIO` is deprecated. I have not been able to find it, but that does not mean it doesn't exist. Objects of class `Serial` also have a `write` method according to this documentation.

Comment: so it is initialized as `ser = serialIO.serialIO(portname,baudrate)`. if this is returning NoneType, does that mean it didn't find serialIO? Again, nothing has changed in years, but perhaps something about how the libraries are stored. The system is backed up regularly. I don't know how to diagnose this.

Comment: I have problems finding the documentation of that function. Which library is it in? I have found however this [report of a bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyserial/bugs/158/), which talks about a change in serialIO write now accepting bytes instead of a string. So it might be the case that some other things have changed. Maybe the serialIO class is initialized now in a different way. But I do not seem to be able to find the exact code.

Comment: Oh, I think I found it, but might it be the case that it has changed to a class called Serial? http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#classes. I edited my answer to make it a little bit more useful. Hope it helps.

Comment: you are right, the library is serial. SerialIO is a wrapper for serial.

Comment: is it a wrapper available somewhere or was it implemented by you? Maybe the problem is in this initialization and the returning of the created object.

Comment: I did not write the wrapper. Not sure if it is publicly available. In any case, i think this is the wrong tree, since nothing in the code has changed. It seems it's a system thing.

Comment: Hm... I guess it is difficult to tell without being able to see the actual `SerialIO` code or knowing what exactly changed in the system. I just find it strange that a system change leads to that kind of error, unless it is the actual code of `SerialIO` what has changed. But maybe I am missing something :/

Comment: Yes, @cnluzon is right, i traced it to where i initialize the self.ser class. I checked his answer, and included my own long answer for completeness, along with my wrapper for PySerial.

Answer (score 1):

OK, i figured it out. I traced the failure to instantiation of opening a COM port (debugging in Komodo IDE was very helpful). It failed to open the port, and while the wrapper (below) for pyserial caught the error, my code didn't do anything about it. So when i tried to use serial methods, i.e. `ser.write()' (where ser is my port instance) i get the AttributeError.

The port failed to open because of the box on the other end wasn't communicating properly. Resetting this box (a motor controller) fixed the problem.

The wrapper I use for PySerial appears to be in-house code---short but useful. I am sharing it here:

SerialIO: Wrapper for PySerial

```py
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#  serialIO: wrappers for pyserial module for exception handling, etc. 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# depends on http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/

import serial
import sys
import time

    #####################################  serial handlers
    # all serial commands except stop are filtererd through this


class serialIO():

    def __init__(self,port, baudrate, timeout=0.0,echo=False,rtscts=False):

        self.port = port
        self.br = baudrate
        self.to = timeout
        self.echo = echo
        self.rtscts = rtscts
        self.stdout = False
        self.ser = None
        self.status = "OK"
        self.reopen()


    def reopen(self):    
        # first close it if it's already open
        if self.ser:
            try:
                self.ser.close()
            except serial.SerialException, v:
                self.status = "error"

        # do we want stdout (for debug)?
        if self.port == "stdout":
            self.stdout = True
            self.ser = sys.stdout
        else:                   # nope, actually open the prort
            try:  # xonxoff=True hoses binary polling of Faulhabers!
                self.ser = serial.Serial(self.port, self.br, 
                                         timeout=self.to,
                                         rtscts =self.rtscts,
                                         xonxoff=False)  
            except serial.SerialException, v:
                self.status = "error"
                print str(v)
        return(self.status)


    def echo(self,str):
        pass


    # write the given string to the serial device, catching exceptions
    def safewrite(self,string,flush=True): 
        try:
            result = self.ser.write(string)
            if flush:
                if self.stdout:
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                else:
                    self.ser.flushOutput()
        except serial.SerialException, v:           
            print str(v)
            return(-1)

        return(result)

    def REALLYflushInput(self):
        """ because ser.flushInput() doesn't seem to work :/"""
        if self.stdout:
            return
        self.ser.flushInput()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        #self.ser.flushInput()
        readstr = ""
        incount = self.ser.inWaiting()
        while (incount > 0):
            readstr += self.ser.read(incount)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            incount = self.ser.inWaiting()



    # write the given string to the serial device
    def write(self,string,flush=True): 
        self.ser.write(string)
        if flush:
            if self.stdout:
                sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                self.ser.flushOutput()

    def read(self,nb):
        return(self.ser.read(nb))

    # returns number of bytes successfully read, -1 if error
    def saferead(self):
        if self.stdout:
            return("",0)
        nread = 0
        try:
            incount = self.ser.inWaiting()
        except serial.SerialException, v: 
            incount = 0
            raise
        rstr = ""
        while (incount > 0):
            try:
                rstr += self.ser.read(incount)
            except serial.SerialException, v:           
                print str(v)
                return(rstr,-1)
            nread = nread + incount
            incount = self.ser.inWaiting()
        return(rstr,nread)

    def readstr(self):
        incount = self.ser.inWaiting()
        readstring = ""
        while (incount > 0):
            readstring += self.ser.read(incount)
            incount = self.ser.inWaiting()
        if self.echo:
            self.log("read %s" % readstring)
        return readstring

    # resturn a list of available serial devices            
def GetPortList(plist):
#    for port in portlist:
    if len(plist) < 1:
        # if no list of portnames, make one
        plist = ['COM2','COM3','COM4','COM5']
    OKports = []
    for port in plist:
        ser = None
        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)  
        except serial.SerialException, v:
            #print str(v)
            pass
        else:
            OKports.append(ser.name)
        finally:
            if(ser):
                ser.close()
    return OKports


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plist = GetPortList([])
    print str(plist)
```